# Finding the interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ((-1)^n2^n(x-3)^nn!)/(n^n)$

Tags: calculus, power-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  (-1)^n \frac{n!(2^n)(x-3)^n}{n^n} $$

this is what I tried:

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{(n+1)n!2^{(n+1)}(x-3)^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)^{(n+1)}} \cdot \
\frac{n^n}{n!2^n(x-3)^n} \right| \\
=|2(x-3)| \lim_{n\to \infty}\left( \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n} \right) \\
= |2(x-3)|\cdot \left(\frac1{1+0}\right)^n
 $$

then I set $|2(x-3)| < 1$

$$|(x-3)| < 1/2$$

$$R = 1/2$$

$$2 < x < \frac72$$

then I plugged $2$ into $x$ and take the ratio test to see if I get divergent or convergent, but I ended up with $1$ which is inconclusive... I think I'm stuck and I'm not sure if I did this whole problem right.. I don't think I'm very good at these yet... can someone please step through the whole thing for me please?

Comment: Since the sequence is alternating, the sum will converge iff the sequence itself goes toward $0$.

Comment: is everyone sure the interval is [2,7/2] ? i think it might actually be [5/2,7/2]

Comment: See the answer here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty+%28%28-1%29%5En+2%5En+%28x-3%29%5En+n%21%29%2F%28n%5En%29

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:*
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}
=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}
=
\cdots
$$

Comment: um... cant you see that i did that...

Comment: @mathisatroll, no, because you write it as $(1/(1+0))^n$, which is not right.

Comment: ohhh... its 1/e

Comment: so they both evaluate to 1/e which makes the interval have brackets. so can anyone confirm that R = 1/2 and interval = [2, 7/2] ? I have no way to check my answer to make sure its right :(